# Not immediately receiving props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-props, react-state

I am trying to pass props to a child component through react router, link.When I reload the page the console logs 3 times, the first log is undefined, the second shows the data i need and the third log shows undefined again.What am I doing wrong ?

This component is where I am making the external API call and grabbing the data, which I then store to state

```
class CryptoList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        }
    }
    componentDidMount = async () => {
        await this.coinCall()
    }

    coinCall = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await ApiData()
            this.setState({
                data: data
            })
        }
        catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }

    render() {

        const coinsArray = Array.from(this.state.data)
        const coins = coinsArray.map(coin => (
            <div><Link
                key={coin.id}
                to={{
                    pathname: `/ CoinInfo`,
                    state: { data: coin.name, }
                }}
            >
                <Coin
                    pathname={CoinInfo}
                    render={CoinInfo}
                    coinId={coin.name}
                    price={coin.market_data.current_price.usd}
                    image={coin.image.small}
                />
            </Link>
            </div>
        ))
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>{coins}</ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Below is the component where I want to display the data and it appears to be rendering three times

```
class CoinInfo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
        this.setState({ data: props })
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        let data = this.state.data
        console.log("$$$", this.props)
        return (<div>{data}</div>)
    }
    render() {
        console.log("**********", this.props.data)
        return (
            <div>
                <p>working</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are sending state with the link, you are able to send the data with the link, and access it by getting it in the component it is routed to, like so: `this.props.location.state`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be doing `setState` in constructor. Instead initialize the state with props like this.

```
class CoinInfo extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            data: props
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover it looks like you don't even need need local state, you can directly use `this.props.data` inside your render function.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and I got the same result with three logs, the first and third being undefined and the second one showing the data